# How does system command behave under Perl and CGI

Tags: perl, concurrency, cgi

I have a Perl script under cgi with the following:

```
system ("echo mystuff > myfile.txt")
```

If I hit this with two requests simultaneously, do both requests try to write to myfile, or does it block since system causes a fork and pauses parent process until child finishes?

Comment: Yes. One workaround is to write to a unique file in each script, say `myfile.$$.txt` where `$$` -- in Perl and in sh -- is replaced by the current process id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is executed twice in parallel, then both instance of it will call the `system` command and it is possible that the output of the `echo` will get garbled. This happen under CGI or if you run the script directly in the command line. If you don't like that, you can use something like [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) to ensure that only one process is ran at a time, although you should be very careful if you do that.

Comment: This is legacy and seems to appear to be running valid. The only method to block is flock; there would be no configuration setting on apache that could limit number of instances? It would/could be rare occurrence?

Comment: @paulj There may very well be an apache setting that makes apache run a single instance of the CGI script, but I don't think this is a good idea. The solution where you handle the blocking yourself offers better granularity. You could also use `flock` within bash, e.g. `system ("flock /path/to/lockfile echo mystuff > myfile.txt")` but the perl solution would have better performance.

Answer (score 1):

With conventional CGI, your two requests will be run in two different processes. Neither will block the other. If you are unlucky (or have enough traffic), race conditions might garble the contents of `myfile.txt`.